# Is there a mean-variance normalization layer in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, normalization

I am new to PyTorch and I would like to add a mean-variance normalization layer to my network that will normalize features to zero mean and unit standard deviation. I got a bit confused reading the documentation, could anyone give me some leads?

Comment: There are multiple types of normalization layers available: *batch-*, *group-*, *layer-*, *instance-* wise. The question is: over what are you standardizing your values?

Answer (score 1):

As @Ivan commented, the normalization can be done on many levels. However, as You say

> normalize features to zero mean and unit standard deviation

I suppose You just want to input unbiased data to the network. If that's the case, You should treat it as data preprocessing step rather than a layer of Your model and basically do:

```
X = (X - torch.mean(X, dim=0))/torch.std(X, dim=0)
```

As an alternative, You can use `torchvision.transforms`:

```
preprocess = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=torch.mean(X, dim=0), std=torch.std(X, dim=0))
X = preprocess(X)
```

as in [this](https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_resnet/) ResNet native example. Note how it is reasonably assumed that the future data would always have roughly the same mean and std_dev as the set that is used for their initial calculation (supposedly the training set). For this reason, we should preserve the initially calculated values and use them for preprocessing in any future inference scenario.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you are referring to normalizing on a global level...*

Note that obtaining a zero-mean/unit-variance normalization is a delicate issue, because it requires to infer the parameters globally, i.e., from the entire training data, not just from a small subset like a micro batch. Therefore it typically has to be solved externally of the regular training loop, and the solution can also depend on the particular problem/dataset. Another thing to keep in mind: When splitting the data into train/test/validation one must be careful to "learn" the normalization only on the training data, i.e., in general it is not desirable to infer a different normalization from the test/validation datasets (because that is not how the model would operate in a productive setting).

That being said, it is possible to wrap the transformation itself into an `torch.nn.Module`. Here is an example that "learns" the normalization parameters from a given numpy matrix.

```py
class Normalizer(torch.nn.Module):
    feature_means: torch.Tensor
    feature_stds: torch.Tensor

    @staticmethod
    def create_on_data(X: np.ndarray) -> Normalizer:
        n_features = X.shape[1]
        feature_means = torch.zeros(n_features)
        feature_stds = torch.zeros(n_features)

        for j in range(n_features):
            feature_means[j] = float(np.mean(X[:, j]))
            feature_stds[j] = float(np.std(X[:, j]))

        return Normalizer(feature_means, feature_stds)

    def __init__(self, feature_means: torch.Tensor, feature_stds: torch.Tensor):
        super().__init__()
        self.register_buffer("feature_means", feature_means)
        self.register_buffer("feature_stds", feature_stds)

    def forward(self, X: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        return (X - self.feature_means) / self.feature_stds
```

This can now be used from your actual model, but again the construction somehow needs to "see" the entire dataset.

```py
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    @staticmethod
    def create_on_data(X: np.ndarray) -> MyModel:
        normalizer = Normalizer.create_on_data(X)
        return MyModel(normalizer=normalizer)

    def __init__(self, normalizer: Normalizer):
        super().__init__()
        self.normalizer = normalizer
        # More things here...

    def forward(self, X: torch.Tensor) -> tuple[torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor]:
        X = self.normalizer.forward(X) # normalizes X
        output = ...
        return output
```